# PHP code to get Email Addresses from LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

Is it possible to get email addresses stored in LDAP and send a mail through PHP? The names will be saved in a dropdown box. Once we choose one name from the dropdown the respective email ID should be picked from LDAP and a mail should be sent to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access LDAP with PHP (LDAP support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to use the --with-ldap[=DIR] configuration option )

Here is the full PHP documentation on the subject: (http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php)

Here is a basic example how you can access LDAP and retrieve information from PHP's documentation.

```
<?php
// basic sequence with LDAP is connect, bind, search, interpret search
// result, close connection

echo "<h3>LDAP query test</h3>";
echo "Connecting ...";
$ds=ldap_connect("localhost");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
echo "connect result is " . $ds . "<br />";

if ($ds) { 
    echo "Binding ..."; 
    $r=ldap_bind($ds);     // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically
                           // read-only access
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

    echo "Searching for (sn=S*) ...";
    // Search surname entry
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "o=My Company, c=US", "sn=S*");  
    echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

    echo "Number of entries returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

    echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
        echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
        echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
    }

    echo "Closing connection";
    ldap_close($ds);

} else {
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick response, but this is the error I am getting

ldap_search(): Search: Operations error on line 18
ldap_count_entries() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given on line 21
ldap_get_entries() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given  on line 24

and this is the output

Connecting ...connect result is Resource id #2
Binding ...Bind result is 1
Searching for (sn=S*) ...Search result is 
Number of entries returned is 
Getting entries ...
Data for items returned:

Closing connection

I am completely new to this.

Comment: Check your binding. The function ldap_bind accepts 2 more parameters bind_rdn and bind_password if there are not provided anonymous bind is executed: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. I defined the username and password in the ldap bind for it to work :) Appreciate your assistance. :)